# conda-build using an old (stale) setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, conda-build

I am trying to generate a conda package (using conda-build) from some python source files and other DLL files. I first use a setup.py file to generate the python source code tar.gz file in the dist folder. All this works fine.

Then I am trying to create a conda tarball (tar.bz2) file by using conda-build. However it bombs out saying it cannot fine py2exe in setup.py. I had imported py2exe in the setup.py as an experiment at one point but have removed it since. The current setup.py does not have this import. So, I'm not sure why conda-build is still complaining about this. I even tried deleting all the files and directories that I think might be causing the problem and starting from scratch and it still complains. So, it's using a cached file from somewhere but I have no idea where. My bld.bat that conda-build uses is simply this:

```
%PYTHON% setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

My recipe file is:

```
package:
  name: projectname
  version: 1.0.0

source:
  url: ../dist/projectname-1.0.0.tar.gz

build:
  number: 1
  include_recipe: True

requirements:
  build:
    - python
  run:
    - python
```

Here is the relevant output of conda-build:

> (%BUILD_PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>%BUILD_PREFIX%\python.exe setup.py install
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 2, in
>   
>       import py2exe ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2exe'
>
> (%BUILD_PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>if errorlevel 1 exit 1 Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "d:\Continuum\anaconda3.5\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 10, in
>   
>       sys.exit(main())

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. For anyone else who may experience this issue, I did a global search for setup.py and found the offending file in the conda-bld folder that conda-build generates. I deleted the conda-bld and it resolved the issue.